# Resizing an image with Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5, intervention

Im trying to use Intervention with AWS S3, but the resize method is not working for me.

```
$img = Image::make($file)->rotate($rotate)->crop($width, $width, $x, $y);
$img->backup();

foreach(Config::get('img.image-sizes') as $_k => $_v){
    $img->resize($_v['w'], $_v['h']);
    $s3->queue($img, $name);
    $img->reset();
}
```

The images upload fine to S3, but resize fails, I get all images the size of the original image

If I call save() on the image, the resize works, but I do not wish to save the image as I am uploading via S3, putting the $img as the body:

```
$this->commands[] = $this->s3->getCommand('PutObject', [
        'Bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'Key' => Config::get('img.image-path').$name,
        'Body' => $img,
        'ContentType' => $img->mime(),
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ]);
```

To get this to work will I have to call save on each image first? If so is there a way to get this to play nice with S3, ideally I do not want to save them to my server first before sending them off to S3.

Comment: What is actually wrong with the idea of saving the resized images locally before they're sent to S3? After you send them, delete them. They will be stored locally and deleted during one request.

Comment: What plugin are you using to send to S3 btw? curious.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to get my uploaded images resized and saved to Amazon S3 using Laravel 5 and Intervention.

```
$imageFile = \Image::make($imageUpload)->resize(600, 600)->stream();
$imageFile = $imageFile->__toString();

$filename = 'myFileName.png';

$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$s3_response = $s3->put('/'.$filename, $imageFile, 'public');
```